# How To Only Selectively Read Numbers and/or Words From a .txt File?

Tags: java, file, linked-list, fileinputstream

I have a simple **.txt file** ("theFile.txt") with the following format where the left column are the `lineNumber` and the right column are the `word`:

```
5     today
2     It's
1     "
4     sunny
3     a
6     "
```

For this txt file, I'm making **two separate methods** to **each** get **only** the number and **only** the string, plus another method to scan the file and put each `lineNumber` and `word` in a double-linked list `DLL`:

```
  String fileName = "theFile.txt";

  public int getNumberOnly() {
       int lineNumber;

       //code to only get the lineNumber but NOT the words
       //This is as far as I got and I need help on this part

       return lineNumber;
  }

  public String getWordsOnly() {
       String words;

       //code to only get the words but NOT the lineNumber
       //This is as far as I got and I need help on this part

       return words;
  }

  public void readAndPrintWholeFile(String fileName){

          String fileContents = new String();
          File file = new File("theFile.txt");
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName));
          DLL<T> list = new DLL<T>();

         //Print each lineNumber and corresponding words for example
         // 5   Today
         // 2   It's

         while (scanner.hasNextLine())
         {
              fileContents = scanner.nextLine();
              System.out.println(list.getNumbersOnly() + " " +  list.getWordOnly());  
              //prints the lineNumber then space then the word
         }
  }

  //I already have all DLL accessors and mutators such as get & set next/previous nodes here, etc.
```

I'm stuck on how to code the method bodies for both `getNumbersOnly()` and `getWordOnly()`

I've tried my best to get to this point.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the point of putting this into two methods? Is this for homework?

Comment: It's an exercise -- I'm asking here because I've exhausted all I know.

Comment: are the numbers and words seperated by space uniformly for all lines ?

Comment: @RahulSingh As far as I know, it's just a simple .txt file so the only separators are whitespace between the numbers and words and then a "new line" after each word

Comment: @RahulSingh yes, they're separated uniformly by whitespace.

Comment: then its easy you can have a single method which will seperate the lines when ever it encounters space and you will get a word and a number for each line,hope this solves your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void readAndPrintWholeFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String fileContents;
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        try {
            fileContents = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] as = fileContents.split(" +");
            map.put(as[0], as[1]);
            System.out.println(as[0] + " " + as[1]);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            //If some problam with File formate e.g. number without word
        }
    }
}
```

You can do this in many way and one of them is hear.
Hera I am not implemented `getNumberOnly()` and `getWordsOnly()` method and I d't have DLL implementation so put data in `map`(`HashMap`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass "fileContents" as the parameter to the functions.

```
public int getNumberOnly(String fileContents) {
   int lineNumber;
   //Get position of space
   int spacePos = fileContents.indexOf(" ");
   //Get substring from start till first space is encountered. Also trim off any leading or trailing spaces. Convert string to int via parseInt
   lineNumber = parseInt(fileContents.subString(0,spacePos).trim());
   return lineNumber;
}

public String getWordsOnly(String fileContents) {
   String words;
   int spacePos = fileContents.indexOf(" ");
   //Get substring from first space till the end
   words = fileContents.subString(spacePos).trim();
   return words;
}
```